# cakephp: how to set multiple validation in model for different actions?

Tags: php, cakephp, validation

I have a user model. In it, I have set validations that are used while registering user. That works fine. But when user edits his profile information, I don't want to validate some fields like password, email, etc. How it is possible. Below is code.

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel{

    var $name = 'User';

    // used when user registers
    var $validate = array(

        'login' => array(
            'minLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),
                'field' => 'login', 
                'message' => 'mimimum 6 characters long'
                )
        ),
        'password' => array( // don't want to validate in edit profile page
            'minLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),
                'field' => 'password',
                'message' => 'minimum 6 characters long'
                )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'please enter a valid email address'
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

Above is used when I register a user. But when user edits his profile, I don't allow to edit/change user password. So each time while editing profile, it checks for password validation. I haven't added password field in edit profile page, I don't want to validate password field. So can I have different validation rules for different actions?

Thanks.

Comment: if you dont want to validate password and email, dont call password and email or another name inside your validate script

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Several ways to do this:

- Use the [`on` parameter](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1145/One-Rule-Per-Field#on-1149) to apply rules only to *create* or *update* actions.
- `unset` the undesired rules from the model before validation.

  ```
  unset($this->User->validate['password']);
  ```
- Use [custom validation methods](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1181/Adding-your-own-Validation-Methods) that are intelligent enough to figure out whether they should apply or not, e.g. by checking whether `$this->id` or `$data['id']` is set or not. Not recommended unless you're sure what you're doing.
- Use the `$fieldlist` parameter of the [`save` method](http://book.cakephp.org/complete/1000/Models#Saving-Your-Data-1031) to limit saving and validation to specified fields only. Fields not in the list will neither be saved nor validated. Very recommended, since it also protects against form spoofing.

  ```
  $this->User->save($this->data, true, array('only', 'certain', 'fields'));
  ```

Comment: can you give me an e.g. of $this->User->save($this->data, true, array('only', 'certain', 'fields'));

Comment: how to validate with specified fields only using $this->User->save($this->data, true, array('only', 'certain', 'fields'));  ?

Comment: @lakum Replace `array('only', 'certain', 'fields')` with an array of field names you want to validate and save, like `array('login', 'email')` to validate and save only the `login` and `email` fields.

Comment: I am using this. $this->User->saveAll($this->data, array('validate'=>'first')); then what should be there? I am confused.

Comment: @lakum Please read the manual section "Saving your data" I linked to, the part about the `saveAll` method. It lists `'fieldlist'` as an option. You use it like this: `$this->User->saveAll($this->data, array('validate' => 'first', 'fieldlist' => array('login', 'email')))`.

Answer (score 0):

just do until this:

```
var $validate = array(

        'login' => array(
            'minLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),
                'field' => 'login', 
                'message' => 'mimimum 6 characters long'
                )
        ),
```

for a simple way to validate try [jquery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

Comment: but it will not work while registering user. I want all fields validated in register action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel{

    var $name = 'User';

    // used when user registers
    var $validate = array(

        'login' => array(
            'minLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),
                'field' => 'login', 
                'message' => 'mimimum 6 characters long'
                )
        ),
        'password' => array( // don't want to validate in edit profile page
            'minLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('minLength', '6'),
                'field' => 'password',
                'message' => 'minimum 6 characters long',
                'on' => 'create' //Only perform validation when creating a new record.

                )
        ),
        'email' => array(
            array(
            'rule' => 'email',
            'message' => 'please enter a valid email address'
            )
        )
    );
?>
```

Note the new line in the validation array for password.

This is documented in the [Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1145/One-Rule-Per-Field).

Comment: yes, it will work with create/update. But what if I want to ignore validation in some conditions? for e.g. I don't want to check password validation only when user_type=0; ?